# xslt: convert elements to attributes - returns last elements as attributes only

Tags: xml, templates, xslt, attributes

Attempting to convert elements to attributes of the elements parent node but the code only returns the last elements in the list as attributes

Sample of XML

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<NB xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="file:///C:/Users/xXXXXXX/Documents/xxxxx%20Profile%20XML/Untitled13.xsd">
    <Profile>
        <PName>165370 - XXX - XXXXXX</PName>
        <OrderID>165370</OrderID>
        <Status>I</Status>
        <OrderInst/>
        <TopicInst>OMIT MERE MENTIONS</TopicInst>
        <KeywordInst>
            <OrderKWs>
                <KW>KEEPHILLS</KW>
                <KWInst>ICW KEEPHILLS POWER PLANT
OR ICW POWER GENERATION AT KEEPHILLS PLANT</KWInst>
                <KW>SUN 7 PLANT</KW>
                <KWInst>ICW SUNDANCE GAS FIRED POWER PLANT
OR ICW SUNDANCE COAL FIRED POWER PLANT
OR ICW ELECTRICAL POWER GENERATION AT SUNDANCE PLANT
OMIT SUNDANCE FILM FESTIVAL</KWInst>
                <KW>SUNDANCE 7 GAS PLANT</KW>
                <KWInst>ICW POWER PLANT
OR ICW POWER GENERATION</KWInst>
                <KW>SUNDANCE AND COAL</KW>
                <KWInst>ICW SUNDANCE GAS FIRED POWER PLANT
OR ICW SUNDANCE COAL FIRED POWER PLANT
OR ICW ELECTRICAL POWER GENERATION AT SUNDANCE PLANT
OMIT SUNDANCE FILM FESTIVAL</KWInst>
                <KW>SUNDANCE AND ELECTRIC</KW>
                <KWInst>ICW SUNDANCE GAS FIRED POWER PLANT
OR ICW SUNDANCE COAL FIRED POWER PLANT
OR ICW ELECTRICAL POWER GENERATION AT SUNDANCE PLANT
OMIT SUNDANCE FILM FESTIVAL</KWInst>
                <KW>SUNDANCE AND ELECTRICAL</KW>
                <KWInst>ICW SUNDANCE GAS FIRED POWER PLANT
OR ICW SUNDANCE COAL FIRED POWER PLANT
OR ICW ELECTRICAL POWER GENERATION AT SUNDANCE PLANT
OMIT SUNDANCE FILM FESTIVAL</KWInst>
                <KW>SUNDANCE AND ELECTRICITY</KW>
                <KWInst>ICW SUNDANCE GAS FIRED POWER PLANT
OR ICW SUNDANCE COAL FIRED POWER PLANT
OR ICW ELECTRICAL POWER GENERATION AT SUNDANCE PLANT
OMIT SUNDANCE FILM FESTIVAL</KWInst>
                <KW>SUNDANCE AND GAS</KW>
                <KWInst>ICW SUNDANCE GAS FIRED POWER PLANT
OR ICW SUNDANCE COAL FIRED POWER PLANT
OR ICW ELECTRICAL POWER GENERATION AT SUNDANCE PLANT
OMIT SUNDANCE FILM FESTIVAL</KWInst>
                <KW>SUNDANCE AND GENERATION</KW>
                <KWInst>ICW SUNDANCE GAS FIRED POWER PLANT
OR ICW SUNDANCE COAL FIRED POWER PLANT
OR ICW ELECTRICAL POWER GENERATION AT SUNDANCE PLANT
OMIT SUNDANCE FILM FESTIVAL</KWInst>
                <KW>SUNDANCE AND PLANT</KW>
                <KWInst>ICW SUNDANCE GAS FIRED POWER PLANT
OR ICW SUNDANCE COAL FIRED POWER PLANT
OR ICW ELECTRICAL POWER GENERATION AT SUNDANCE PLANT
OMIT SUNDANCE FILM FESTIVAL</KWInst>
                <KW>SUNDANCE AND POWER</KW>
                <KWInst>ICW SUNDANCE GAS FIRED POWER PLANT
OR ICW SUNDANCE COAL FIRED POWER PLANT
OR ICW ELECTRICAL POWER GENERATION AT SUNDANCE PLANT
OMIT SUNDANCE FILM FESTIVAL</KWInst>
                <KW>SUNDANCE UNIT</KW>
                <KWInst>ICW SUNDANCE GAS FIRED POWER PLANT
OR ICW SUNDANCE COAL FIRED POWER PLANT
OR ICW ELECTRICAL POWER GENERATION AT SUNDANCE PLANT
OMIT SUNDANCE FILM FESTIVAL</KWInst>
                <KW>WABAMUN</KW>
                <KWInst>ICW WABUMUM POWER PLANT
OR ICW POWER GENERATION AT WABUMUM PLANT</KWInst>
            </OrderKWs>
        </KeywordInst>
    </Profile>
</NB>
```

XSD

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- W3C Schema generated by XMLSpy v2018 sp1 (http://www.altova.com) -->
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="KW" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="NB">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="Profile"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="PName">
        <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                <xs:enumeration value="165370 - XXX - XXXXXX"/>
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="KWInst" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="Status">
        <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                <xs:enumeration value="I"/>
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="OrderID" type="xs:int"/>
    <xs:element name="Profile">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="PName"/>
                <xs:element ref="OrderID"/>
                <xs:element ref="Status"/>
                <xs:element ref="OrderInst"/>
                <xs:element ref="TopicInst"/>
                <xs:element ref="KeywordInst"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="OrderKWs">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="KW"/>
                <xs:element ref="KWInst"/>
                <xs:element ref="KW"/>
                <xs:element ref="KWInst"/>
                <xs:element ref="KW"/>
                <xs:element ref="KWInst"/>
                <xs:element ref="KW"/>
                <xs:element ref="KWInst"/>
                <xs:element ref="KW"/>
                <xs:element ref="KWInst"/>
                <xs:element ref="KW"/>
                <xs:element ref="KWInst"/>
                <xs:element ref="KW"/>
                <xs:element ref="KWInst"/>
                <xs:element ref="KW"/>
                <xs:element ref="KWInst"/>
                <xs:element ref="KW"/>
                <xs:element ref="KWInst"/>
                <xs:element ref="KW"/>
                <xs:element ref="KWInst"/>
                <xs:element ref="KW"/>
                <xs:element ref="KWInst"/>
                <xs:element ref="KW"/>
                <xs:element ref="KWInst"/>
                <xs:element ref="KW"/>
                <xs:element ref="KWInst"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="OrderInst">
        <xs:complexType/>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="TopicInst">
        <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                <xs:enumeration value="OMIT MERE MENTIONS"/>
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="KeywordInst">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="OrderKWs"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

XSLT

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math" xmlns:array="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/array" xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map" xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:err="http://www.w3.org/2005/xqt-errors" exclude-result-prefixes="array fn map math xhtml xs err" version="3.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates mode="copy" select="."/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*|text()|@*" mode="copy">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates mode="copy" select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates mode="copy"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="//KeywordInst" mode="copy">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates mode="convert-to-attr" select="OrderKWs/*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*" mode="convert-to-attr">
        <xsl:attribute name="{name()}" select="text()"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The Output XML

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<NB xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="file:///C:/Users/gary.larose/Documents/Newbase%20Profile%20XML/Untitled13.xsd">
    <Profile>
        <PName>165370 - XXX - XXXXXX</PName>
        <OrderID>165370</OrderID>
        <Status>I</Status>
        <OrderInst/>
        <TopicInst>OMIT MERE MENTIONS</TopicInst>
        <KeywordInst KW="WABAMUN" KWInst="ICW WABUMUM POWER PLANT&#xA;OR ICW POWER GENERATION AT WABUMUM PLANT"/>
    </Profile>
</NB>
```

Expected Output:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<NB xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="file:///C:/Users/gary.larose/Documents/Newbase%20Profile%20XML/Untitled13.xsd">
    <Profile>
        <PName>165370 - XXX - XXXXXX</PName>
        <OrderID>165370</OrderID>
        <Status>I</Status>
        <OrderInst/>
        <TopicInst>OMIT MERE MENTIONS</TopicInst>
        <KeywordInst  KW="KEEPHILLS" KWInst="ICW KEEPHILLS POWER PLANT OR ICW POWER GENERATION AT KEEPHILLS PLANT"</>
        <KeywordInst KW="SUN 7 PLANT" KWInst="ICW SUNDANCE GAS FIRED POWER PLANT OR ICW SUNDANCE COAL FIRED POWER PLANTOR ICW ELECTRICAL POWER GENERATION AT SUNDANCE PLANTOMIT SUNDANCE FILM FESTIVAL"</>
        <KeywordInst KW="SUNDANCE 7 GAS PLANT" KWInst="ICW POWER PLANT OR ICW POWER GENERATION"</>
        <KeywordInst KW="SUNDANCE AND COAL" KWInst="ICW SUNDANCE GAS FIRED POWER PLANT OR ICW SUNDANCE COAL FIRED POWER PLANT OR ICW ELECTRICAL POWER GENERATION AT SUNDANCE PLANT OMIT SUNDANCE FILM FESTIVAL"</>
        <KeywordInst KW="SUNDANCE AND ELECTRIC" KWInst="ICW SUNDANCE GAS FIRED POWER PLANT OR ICW SUNDANCE COAL FIRED POWER PLANTOR ICW ELECTRICAL POWER GENERATION AT SUNDANCE PLANTOMIT SUNDANCE FILM FESTIVAL"</>
        <KeywordInst KW="SUNDANCE AND ELECTRICAL" KWInst="ICW SUNDANCE GAS FIRED POWER PLANT OR ICW SUNDANCE COAL FIRED POWER PLANT OR ICW ELECTRICAL POWER GENERATION AT SUNDANCE PLANT OMIT SUNDANCE FILM FESTIVAL"</>
        ......
        <KeywordInst KW="WABAMUN" KWInst="ICW WABUMUM POWER PLANT&#xA;OR ICW POWER GENERATION AT WABUMUM PLANT"/>
    </Profile>
</NB>
```

The attribute KW="WABAMUN" and KWInst="ICW...." are the last pair in the sample xml file.  My target file has 150k lines of the same structure, and when I run this XSLT on the target file, the Output (as sampled) appears to always be the last pair of KW and KWInst in the list within the Profile entity.

thank you for your help.
G

Comment: Please show an example of what you _expect_ in addition to the actual output.

Comment: Do you know the names of the elements (i.e. `KW` and `KWInst`) and the number of elements (i.e. two) that are supposed to form the attributes of a new `KeywordInst` element?

Answer (score 1):

If you know the name of the (first) element (e.g. `KW`) to form a new `KeywordInst` element then I think with XSLT 2 or 3 the easiest way is to use e.g. `for-each-group starting-with="KW"` so with XSLT 3 this becomes

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="KeywordInst">
      <xsl:for-each-group select="OrderKWs/*" group-starting-with="KW">
          <xsl:copy select="../..">
              <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()" mode="element-to-attribute"/>
          </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*" mode="element-to-attribute">
      <xsl:attribute name="{name()}" select="."/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/nc4NzPY

With XSLT 2 you need to spell out the identity transformation instead of using the `xsl:mode` declaration and you don't have `xsl:copy select` so you need to use other means like e.g. hardcoding the name with

```
  <xsl:template match="KeywordInst">
      <xsl:for-each-group select="OrderKWs/*" group-starting-with="KW">
          <KeywordInst>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()" mode="element-to-attribute"/>
          </KeywordInst>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:template>
```

but the grouping remains the same.

Comment: thank you greatly Martin - would not have thought to use group - your site is a great resource